# NKAssetDownload addAssetWithRequest apns sigabrt

Tags: objective-c, ios, push-notification, newsstand-kit

I'm normally able to work out why sigabrts happen, but i'm totally stuck on this one.. I'm launching the app from a remote notification, which all works fine until it gets to this bit of code:

```
NKIssue *issueNK = [[NKLibrary sharedLibrary] issueWithName:[issueId stringValue]]; 
if (issueNK == nil) {
    issueNK = [[NKLibrary sharedLibrary] addIssueWithName:[issueId stringValue] date:[NSDate date]];  
}

NSMutableDictionary* settings = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"plist"]] autorelease];
NSURL *downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:[settings objectForKey:@"IssueBundleUrl"], [issue.issueId intValue]]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:downloadURL];
NKAssetDownload *assetDownload = [issueNK addAssetWithRequest:request]; //sigabrt on this line
[assetDownload downloadWithDelegate:issueListViewController];
```

in the debugger, issueNK and request both seem to be fine, not nil or anything.

any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the only reason you would see an exception on that line, is if the issue has already been downloaded or is being downloaded. So you need to check the status of your issue first:

```
NKIssue *issueNK = [[NKLibrary sharedLibrary] issueWithName:[issueId stringValue]]; 
if (issueNK == nil) {
    issueNK = [[NKLibrary sharedLibrary] addIssueWithName:[issueId stringValue] date:[NSDate date]];  
}

if ([issueNK status] != NKIssueContentStatusNone)
    return;

NSMutableDictionary* settings = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"plist"]] autorelease];
NSURL *downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:[settings objectForKey:@"IssueBundleUrl"], [issue.issueId intValue]]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:downloadURL];
NKAssetDownload *assetDownload = [issueNK addAssetWithRequest:request];
[assetDownload downloadWithDelegate:issueListViewController];
```

Comment: thanks, have a tick. note - you don't seem to see the exceptions in the console when the debugger is running in the "wait for app to launch" way.